# ReferenceError: getTemplate is not defined

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs, megamenu

I'm currently working on Megamenu on Magento 2.3, I'm able to edit menu on chrome but after coming to Firefox I'm not able to edit it and I'm getting error in the console it says `ReferenceError: getTemplate is not defined`.

[image]

So how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have write cutom js comewhere?

Comment: No, I haven't written any custom JS files @WaqarAli